# missing results django-haystack with solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am using `django-haystack` with `solr` backend. I've saved three songs in model. When I search for `q="Hello world"`. Its displaying only one result. It should be three. Also copied `schema.xml` and updated the index `rebuild_index`. Am i missing something? thanks

- Hello World
- hello
- World

Here is my search index.

```
class SongIndex(indexes.RealTimeSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
  title = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')

  def get_model(self):
    return Song
```

SearchQuery

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Song).filter(title=AutoQuery('Hello World'))
```

Update: Tried

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Song).filter(title='Hello World')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Song).filter(title='Hello World')
```

Comment: So last thing: you are talking about what this SearchQuerySet returns or really searching for term "Hello World" using Haystack view?

Comment: I am not searching for the exact term and not using Haystack View. simple SearchQuerySet

Comment: But wait... if those three titles are indexed it is normal that it will return only the first one - it is what you are searching for directly - Song with title "Hello World", no matter it is EdgeNgramField.